# How do I get Move Mailbox history?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, mailbox

The following command gives me partial detail on a mailbox move

```
get-mailbox user@company.com | Get-MailboxStatistics -IncludeMoveHistory | ft DisplayName, MoveHistory
```

However I'm interested in getting both the source and destination, and other move details.  How can I modify this command to expand on the additional information embedded in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't figured out how to make this a one liner, this will accomplish what I need

```
$hist = (Get-MailboxStatistics "joe@company.com"  -IncludeMoveHistory).MoveHistory
$hist | select *time*, *data*
```

Comment: Have you tried `(Get-MailboxStatistics "joe@company.com"  -IncludeMoveHistory).MoveHistory | select *time*, *data*`? :-)